# Spring Boot - Generic DAO layer with Hibernate, problems with Autowiring the DAO implementations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a generic way of implementing CRUD operations for different entities with postgresql by following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/simplifying-the-data-access-layer-with-spring-and-java-generics.

Here's the classes for the DAO layer:

```
public interface IGenericDao<T extends Serializable> {

    T findOne(final long id);

    List<T> findAll();

    T create(final T entity);

    T update(final T entity);

    void delete(final T entity);

    void deleteById(final long entityId);
}

public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao<T extends Serializable>
        implements IGenericDao<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public AbstractHibernateDao(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        if (factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }

        sessionFactory = factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

        try {
            persistentClass = ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                    .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public T findOne(long id) {

        return (T) getCurrentSession().
                get(persistentClass, id);
    }

    public List findAll() {

        return getCurrentSession().
                createQuery("from " + persistentClass.getName())
                .list();
    }

    public T create(T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);

        return entity;
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public void deleteById(long entityId) {
        T entity = findOne(entityId);

        delete(entity);
    }

    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}

@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class GenericHibernateDao<T extends Serializable>
        extends AbstractHibernateDao<T>{

    @Autowired
    public GenericHibernateDao(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }
}
```

The problems arises when i try to get the current session from the session factory in AbstractHibernateDao. Both inner fields of AbstractHibernateDao are null ("persistentClass" and "sessionFactory"). Why is that so?

Here is the full stack trace for the Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at com.slupov.dao.AbstractHibernateDao.getCurrentSession(AbstractHibernateDao.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.slupov.dao.AbstractHibernateDao.findAll(AbstractHibernateDao.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.slupov.dao.AbstractHibernateDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$11991ea4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.slupov.dao.GenericHibernateDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7c8fc19.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.slupov.controllers.FileDownloadController.downloadPDFResource(FileDownloadController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

It appears that the context cannot be found but I've explicitly pointed it out in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SlupovPersonal?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Sigma255!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.show_sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.current_session_context_class=thread

spring.jpa.properties.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.dbcp2.maxTotal=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.maxIdle=10
spring.datasource.dbcp2.minIdle=5
spring.datasource.dbcp2.maxWaitMillis=-1

spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Here's the github repo to my project: https://github.com/Slupov/SlupovPersonal/tree/dev/HibernateConnection.
**Please notice the problem is on the dev/HibernateConnection branch!!**

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the property should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` you've missed the `.hibernate` in the path

Comment: @Imaguest thanks but that did not make any positive changes

Comment: @NathanHughes thanks for pointing this out for me. I'm obviously pretty new to Spring and can't still work out what exactly to use and how. I'm basically trying to write less code by trying to make the data access services for similar entities generic. Is there a Spring built in way of doing this and what should i google?

Comment: Why? Spring Data JPA supports this out-of-the-box (and more). Why reinvent the wheel. Also your configuration is broken remove `spring.jpa.properties.current_session_context_class=thread` unless you want transactional issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, just was not sure about using it. You were all correct. Thank you for helping me out by pointing me into the right direction <3